# Database source for Azure Time Series Insights

Tags: azure, azure-timeseries-insights

Can data stored in a database be used in Time Series Insights as the source? I have timeseries data in csv or data form. Can I use it as a source for Time Series Insights?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No not directly. At the moment it only supports IoT Hub and Event Hub as sources. What you could do is create a process that reads the csv data and sends it to an Event Hub that in turn is the source for Azure Time Series Insights. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/time-series-insights/time-series-insights-send-events#sample-code-to-push-events) for sample code to send data to an Event Hub.